# phantom jvm memory usage, native allocations, and sizing k8s pods

Tags: java, jvm, kubernetes-pod

I have a Spring application (`openjdk 11.0.6`) running on a linux docker image (`openjdk:11-jre-slim`) deployed to k8s. I started investigating the app's memory usage so that I can size memory `request` and `limit` values for the pod, and noticed some strange memory usage. Highlights are as follows:

- 4GB node
- 1GB pod memory limit

```
ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax | sort -b -k3 -r
    1 root     20.4 java ...
 2565 root      0.0 sort -b -k3 -r
 2564 root      0.0 ps -o pid,user,%mem,command ax
 2388 root      0.0 bash
  102 root      0.0 bash
  PID USER     %MEM COMMAND
```

```
jcmd 1 VM.native_memory
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1933717KB, committed=565453KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=245760KB, committed=223124KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=245760KB, committed=223124KB) 

-                     Class (reserved=1169540KB, committed=136324KB)
                            (classes #25495)
                            (  instance classes #23876, array classes #1619)
                            (malloc=4228KB #78404) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1165312KB, committed=132096KB) 
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=116736KB, committed=115200KB)
                            (    used=112833KB)
                            (    free=2367KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=16896KB)
                            (    used=15552KB)
                            (    free=1344KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)

-                    Thread (reserved=166301KB, committed=25601KB)
                            (thread #161)
                            (stack: reserved=165500KB, committed=24800KB)
                            (malloc=579KB #809) 
                            (arena=222KB #321)

-                      Code (reserved=254614KB, committed=82974KB)
                            (malloc=6926KB #21050) 
                            (mmap: reserved=247688KB, committed=76048KB) 

-                        GC (reserved=1830KB, committed=1758KB)
                            (malloc=1022KB #3092) 
                            (mmap: reserved=808KB, committed=736KB) 

-                  Compiler (reserved=2121KB, committed=2121KB)
                            (malloc=1991KB #2720) 
                            (arena=131KB #5)

-                  Internal (reserved=33603KB, committed=33603KB)
                            (malloc=33563KB #122858) 
                            (mmap: reserved=40KB, committed=40KB) 

-                     Other (reserved=855KB, committed=855KB)
                            (malloc=855KB #109) 

-                    Symbol (reserved=25799KB, committed=25799KB)
                            (malloc=23073KB #310022) 
                            (arena=2725KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=9062KB, committed=9062KB)
                            (malloc=447KB #6338) 
                            (tracking overhead=8616KB)

-        Shared class space (reserved=17084KB, committed=17084KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=17084KB, committed=17084KB) 

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=6353KB, committed=6353KB)
                            (malloc=6353KB) 

-                   Logging (reserved=4KB, committed=4KB)
                            (malloc=4KB #184) 

-                 Arguments (reserved=18KB, committed=18KB)
                            (malloc=18KB #481) 

-                    Module (reserved=773KB, committed=773KB)
                            (malloc=773KB #4712)
```

```
kubectl top pod app
NAME                               CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
app-XXXXXXX                        661m         827Mi
```

**To sum up**:

- k8s reports pod memory usage of `827Mi`
- `jcmd` reports total memory usage of ~ `560MB`
- `ps` reports 20.4% of system. As I understand, that's a percent of the node's memory so ~ `796MB`

So I have over 200MB of memory usage reported by `ps` which `jcmd` doesn't account for. What am I missing? Does the JVM allocate memory even `jcmd` can't track? As mentioned, my goal is to determine what limits to set on my pods (I'd rather not have them killed under normal usage).

Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: *"Does the JVM allocate memory even jcmd can't track?"* - Yes, see the linked answer.